# Send Bar code from android app to C# desktop application via usb cable

Tags: c#, android

Is it Possible that I can send bar code value from android application to my C# desktop application via Usb Cable. 
I just want to link my two applications via usb cable .. I have searched a lot but still failed..

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use those libraries:

```
SharpUSBLib
LibUsbDotNet
```

They allow to communicate with USB port via C#, and you will be able to read data from USB port in your C# application. Then you need to implement the sending part in your Android application. There is a package `android.hardware.usb` on Android side which contains functionalities for communicating with USB ports. You can use classes from this package to handle the communication.

Comment: Can you share any link or example to implement this ?

Comment: On Android side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808223/send-data-through-usb-from-android-app-to-pc. On C# .NET side, just Google for the library names, and find examples on how to use them.