# Can i communicate through USB with an android APP

Tags: android, usb

I'd like to create a desktop + Android App where the two parties communicate through an USB connection.

I don't want the Android device to be in "Debug USB" mode.

Is it something achievable without having to root the device?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808223/send-data-through-usb-from-android-app-to-pc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ViktorYakunin thanks but still does not cover PC side. Maybe i'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Android Accessory protocol: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/protocol

You need access to the usb device on the desktop side then follow these instructions: https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/aoa#attempt-to-start-in-accessory-mode

I have implemented the "host" side of this before on another Android device and it was pretty straight forward, but there is already a good usb abstraction there. Depending on what your desktop os will depend on how easily you can get to the usb-device to interact with it.

Once you implement it though it gives you a bi-directional data channel to your android app. No debug mode or rooting needed. It will even launch your app automatically when connected and direct the user to the play store to install your app if it isn't installed.